# E/JavaBinder(2275): Unknown binder error code. 0xfffffff7

Tags: android, exception, android-logcat

I'm getting this error on Android application. Any explanation?

LogCat simply write the line in red:

> 03-20 10:31:08.206: E/JavaBinder(2275): Unknown binder error code. 0xfffffff7

**nothing else**.

**EDIT:**

**Solved**. Error arise when I try to unregister a null receiver:

```
unregisterReceiver(screenStatusReceiver);
```

if `screenStatusReceiver` is null I get this error.

**I wonder why the Android framework does not tell anything else** than an unintelligible message...

**EDIT (2):**

The `unregisterReceiver(screenStatusReceiver);` **is called from an AsyncTask.run()**. Maybe, in this case, the Android framework can't arise a complete error message...

Comment: did you forget a permission?

Comment: solved, but strange error message...

Comment: What's the android version of the target platform?

Comment: I'm compiling for 2.3.3, the device version is 4.0.3 (android:minSdkVersion="8", android:targetSdkVersion="8")

Comment: I tried unregisterReceiver(null) in asynctask, not seen "Unknown binder error code", can you post a reproducable code?

Comment: quite complex... I can say the BroadcastReceiver is unregistered from the Application object.

Comment: Maybe it depends on the device I'm using for debug. I'll try also with my HTC phone

Comment: Since you found a solution, you should add an answer to your question. So to remove it from the Unanswered Question Queue.